# iptables out bound port to remote mysql

Tags: centos, iptables

Following is my iptables file on my centos, I am unable to open 3306 port to connect to remote mysql server. I dont know what I am doing wrong although it looks fairly simple.

When I stop the iptable service i can connect to remote mysql on same port as soon as iptable goes on it blocks again.

I have added the last time to open port to the file but it seems to be not working.

Following is iptables file

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.7 on Mon Dec 23 15:32:07 2013
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [396:30624]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [216:23216]
#COMMIT
# Completed on Mon Dec 23 15:32:07 2013
#-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
```

Following is the iptables.save file

```
# Firewall configuration written by system-config-firewall
# Manual customization of this file is not recommended.
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
-A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
-A FORWARD -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
COMMIT
```

Output of iptables restart

```
[root@OV ~]# service iptables restart

iptables: Setting chains to policy ACCEPT: mangle nat filte[  OK  ]

iptables: Flushing firewall rules:                         [  OK  ]

iptables: Unloading modules:                               [  OK  ]

iptables: Applying firewall rules:                         [  OK  ]

[root@OV ~]#
```

Answer (score 0):

You have accept all by default, so, the rules are not needed...

That being said, you should probably have a new rule (just as best practice) that allows all related/established sessions.

I believe that the issue is related to the --dport of the output rule. Try changing it to --sport

This is because, the machine connecting to you will be using a random outgoing port (source port) to connect to the Mysql port (3306/destination on the server), however, when that packet is going back out,  3306 is the source and the random port is the destination.

If you have any enhanced logging on Mysql, You can probably confirm this as it should be receiving requests/your machine should be connecting to it, but, it just isn't getting a response (kind of like a ping without the pong!)

Comment: No luck same situation. But there is something strange when i changed to --sport and restarted iptables it worked and after some time again iptables kicked in and blocked the active connection to remote mysql which i established after restarting iptables

Comment: Make sure the rule didn't switch back / you aren't reloading the save file when restarting the service...

Comment: I am just running "service iptables restart"

Comment: Is that iptables-save thing you sent the entire file? With accept all, it should be working by default... Whilst I said that should be sport instead of dport, that rule shouldn't even be hitting in the first place... It really doesn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: I have added the iptables.save file also to my questions and the output of iptables restart command .  I have noticed that if i stop or shutdown iptables every thing works well but after some times it kicks in again and after starting it stops my mysql outbound connection.  And if i restart iptables it takes around 15-30 seconds to do the same.